# Get started with Android NFC

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, lib-nfc

Im new to the NFC plattform on Android and i would like to get started with an simple NFC app, That read tags and write tags.
Is there any like good guide or libary on this subject?. I have read the android documentation which is a good start but i dont know to proceed from there.

Any kind soul that can point me in the right direction?

Have a nice day!

Comment: This answer covers everything you need (sorry in Java but easy to convert) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819

Comment: Alright i will check it out Andrew thanks :)