# How can I creating a Tag Object in Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, nfc, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to use the Tag Object for my Flutter Plugin. Using MethodChannel I can call the Java functions but my Tag Object remains null. How would I correctly create this Intent?

```
else if (call.method.equals("readTag")) {
      Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
      Tag nfcTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

My guess is that the Intent can't be create in this fashion and thats why it returns a null Object for the Tag.

Comment: Are you sure that `intent` contains value by `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG` key?

Comment: yes, tried out NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG in a separate android application and it worked

Answer (score 0):

As you have created a `new` and empty `Intent` there is nothing to read from it. So as expected.

An `Intent` are really just a generic storage class used generally to pass data in a standard format between one Activity and another.

They use `keys` to pass specific data between Activities. One of the `keys` used by the the System NFC Activity to pass NFC related data to your Activity is the `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG` key.

The Intent has nothing to do with actually reading an NFC Tag, they are just used as a communication method to ask the System NFC Activity to do stuff and how it can returns the data.

So you can create them anywhere you want, with lots of different content and pass them to any Activity to give it data or receive them to be sent data.

You seem to have a miss understanding how NFC works in Android.
The basic concept is.

**Old API's**
You create an `Intent` with basically a "message" to the System NFC App say "I would like to be sent data about specific types of NFC data when one comes in to range", you send that `Intent` message to the System NFC Activity using `enableForegroundDispatch`, when the System NFC App sees a Tag of the right type come in to range it creates an `Intent` to store the data about the NFC tag to send back to the activity that asked for it.
This is using a generic method for inter process communication.

**Newer API's**
Do something similar when you `enableReaderMode` you use an NFC specific method to send data again about about what Tags you are interested in and it sends back the in a more specific format when it sees a Tag of the requested type come in to range.
Example of newer API's https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819

**Manifest Filter**
The Manifest Filter are independent of the Old and New API's, they are about storing information that the System NFC App can use to decide if it should start your App when it sees a particular type of NFC Card. They can be used with both Old and New API's but they pass an `Ìntent` message using the same fields as the Old API to your App, this can be read and processed from `onCreate` using `getIntent`.

So creating a `new` and empty `Intent` and expecting to magically get some NFC data is wrong.

Comment: So using Intents out side of the Activity Class doesn't work?

Comment: Updated answer, Yes they do "work" outside the activity class but possibly not as you expected.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, after a bit of research I noticed there is not much documentation around the new API enableReaderMode. Do you maybe know a Link you could share to read more about it.

Comment: Updated Answer adding a link to a New API example, the new API has full reference documentation just it does not have a "how to" guide of how to connect it together which the example should provide. I also added how "Manifest Filters" fit in to the mix.