# Android: NFC build a Listener for the onTagDiscovered Thread

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm currently working with the enableReaderMode function. I tried out the code from this stack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819
and it worked perfectly.

Now my Issue is, I want to run this function outside of the Activity. So my MAIN Activity calls a function from an outside Class e.g. from a Android Library. Passing the Context Object from my MAIN Activity to the outside Class enables me to use the nfcAdapter.enableRederMode function.
Now the issue is that the `onTagDiscovered` function is never used. This callback function runs on a separated Thread and is being skip.
Is there a way to build a Listener or "join" the Thread so the process only continues once the onTagDiscovered function is used.
In this code example the getNFCMessage runs through without errors but doesn't listen or wait until the Tag is discovered.

```
public class NFCExample implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {

    public void getNFCMessage(NfcAdapter nfcAdapter, Activity activity) {
        if (nfcAdapter != null) {
            Bundle options = new Bundle();
            options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);
            nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(activity,
                    this,
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
                    options);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        System.out.println("Tag Discovered");
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you cannot implement this interface outside of an `Activity` class all I can suggest is start looking around in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/nfc/ as that is where the interface is defined and is the module where it will be called from.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a helpful indication for everyone looking for something simliar. [Link](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/it/matteocrippa/flutternfcreader/FlutterNfcReaderPlugin.kt)

I found this public repo of a flutter plugin which uses the NfcEnableReaderMode function and the Callback onTagDiscovery in a non Activity environment.
It looks like their using a sort of listener to detect the Callback functions once they are used.