# How to prevent my device reading NFC Tags in every Fragment when using NavigationComponent and a single Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nfc, android-architecture-navigation

### Background

I included `Navigation Component` in my app which basically means that I have a single Navigation `Activity` and multiple `Fragments` that display my Views and Data. The app has the ability to read `NFC` Tags from ID Cards.

I followed the implementation guide of Android Developers to include the capability of NFC Tag reading and in their example they edit the Activity in the `AndroidManifest` and enable the `ForegroundDispatcher` in their `Activity`. Since I only have a single Activity basically anywhere in my App the NFC Capability is available.

I'm using `setIntent(intent)` to delegate the incoming `Intents` to my Fragments. Only the Fragment that is supposed to work with NFC handles the Intent while the others just ignore it.

### The Problem

The problem is that when I hold a NFC card close to the phone the phone starts to vibrate since it recognized a NFC device. This happens in every Fragment and is unwanted behavior.

### Question

What can i do about this or am I stuck with this behavior? I read a bit about enabling the `foregroundDispatcher` in a Fragment but the answer was almost always to handle it in my Activity and the function also demands an Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ForegroundDispatcher` (unless you really need to do NFC before API 19) use the newer and better [enableReaderMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) method instead.

The Sound is generated by the system NFC App and with `enableForegroundDispatch` you have no control of the sound plus `enableForegroundDispatch` has a bad side effect of pausing your App to read the NFC Tag and can be unreliable at times especially if writing to the NFC Tag.

With [enableReaderMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) you get to control whether the system NFC App makes a sound or not with the [FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS) flag.

So your design will have to change a bit as the `onTagDiscovered` method is called in another Thread in your application when a NFC Tag is discovered, that thread has to then communicate the data to the Fragment (as it cannot interact with the UI thread directly). One possible method to do this is the `onTagDiscovered` method in the Activity sets a value in a shared view model and then the Fragment that is interested in it "Observes" this value for change and reacts according including making a sound and vibrate itself.

Full example of `enableReaderMode` is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819

Note only enabling `ForeGroundDispatch` NFC in a Fragment is a bad idea, as it is likely the System NFC App will still make a sound anyway when a NFC Tag is presented and because your App might not be handling the event because the Fragment is not running then system NFC App might also show it's own screen over your App as well.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed input! Since I am targeting API23+ I will stick to your up-to-date implementation. I guess with how Android evolves all the time it is important to always check whether the planned implementation is up to date or not.

Also should have been more precise with the way I worded the Intent handling. My Activity is handling the Intent but only the specified Fragment will actually do something with the data received.

Comment: May be my wording on the note was not precise enough, now changed, it was more just confirming what you stated in the question that `enableForegroundDispatch` and `enableReaderMode` should always be done in the Activity's Resume (and Pause) methods and never used directly in a Fragment, Handling the data return can be anywhere