# Android Studio: how to stop reopening activity on each NFC card scanning

Tags: java, android, codeigniter, nfc

I just want that activity should not reopen on each scan, it will stay in the application and when the card is scanned it will simply update the NFC card id in any text view or toast....please help me, i am stuck

Main activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
private String baseUrl = "/api/auth/login";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getRFID();

}

   private void getRFID() {


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();


    if (nfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Card Found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        if (tag == null) {
            // startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, HomeFragment.class));
        } else {
            String tagInfo = "";
            byte[] tagId = tag.getId();
            for (int i = 0; i < tagId.length; i++) {
                tagInfo += Integer.toHexString(tagId[i] & 0xFF) + "";
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, " " + tagInfo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // etEmail.setText(tagInfo.toString());
        }
    } else {
        //  startActivity(new Intent(Login.this , MainActivity.class));
        // finish();
    }


    //  startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));


}
```

}

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71223794/2373819

Comment: @Andrew You can use the "duplicate" close reason for these, which will create a link between the two questions.

Comment: @Ryan M no I cannot use "duplicate" close as the answer I linked is not accepted or up voted as the new user probably has not got the hang of stack overflow yet. This is even though it is the same answer I would give

Comment: @Andrew Oh whoops, my mistake.  You're correct.