# intent.getAction() is null inside onNewIntent() during NFC tag scan

Tags: android, nfc

This is my first time working with NFC Tags. I have declared the NFC scan activity like this in Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".main.NFCScanActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Here is the nfc_tech_filter.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
```

Whenever I scan my tag, onNewIntent() is call but when I try to call intent.getAction() inside onNewIntent, the value is always null.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction(); // action here is null
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code that is responsible for getting the intent?

Comment: Also is this with the App already running in the Foreground or are you trying to start the App when the NFC Tag is scanned?

Comment: @Andrew The app is in foreground

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is more normal to use one of the 2 Foreground NFC API's when you want to handle NFC's when your App is in the Foreground. Usually the Manifest NFC entries are only used to start your App by NFC trigger.

`enableReaderMode` is the better and newer of the 2 Foreground NFC Api's or there is the older `enableForegroundDispatch`

An example of using [enableReaderMode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819)

If using manifest entries for NFC you should really process the return of `getIntent` of your [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()) in `onCreate` to see if that is an Intent created from an NFC trigger.

Comment: enableReaderMode works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted as it as it fixed your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the pending intent flags are set to mutable for nfc.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(
   activity, 
   KEY_PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE,  
   Intent(
      activity,
      activity.javaClass)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 
   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
)
```