# NFC Read/Write on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I have the following code

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 101,
Intent(activity,classType).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
val nfcIntentFilter = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)
val filters = arrayOf(nfcIntentFilter)
val TechLists = arrayOf(arrayOf(Ndef::class.java.name), 
arrayOf(NdefFormatable::class.java.name))
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, TechLists)``
```

and in the activity I am trying to get the tag , action , message

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent)


val type: String? = intent.type
val action: String? = intent.action
 }
```

However, action is already and tag is also null:

```
val tag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
it.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG,Tag::class.java)
} else {
it.getParcelableExtra<Tag>(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
}
```

In the manifest I have the following inside the activity tag:

```
 <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I also have the permission enabled:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

Tried multiple codes and change the intent filter NDEF_DISCOVERED to TAG_DISCOVERD but everything failed. I have tested it also on three separate phones and also same issue. onNewIntent gets called but the intent does not provide information

Comment: Especially if you want to reliably write to a Tag then I would not use `enableForegroundDispatch` but use the better `enableReaderMode` API (Java Example of `enableReaderMode` https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819 )

Comment: Really pointing you to another answer to a similar question does not really justify a separate answer, it's more of a "close" because it's a duplicate, but if like the answer I linked just up vote that answer.

Comment: If you say so thanks anyways