# Sometimes NFC stops working for short period of time

Tags: android, nfc

I am working with NFC smart card.
Typically it is 2-8 commands in a row to get some data, perform some actions and get result.

.

So I call NFC activity from fragment using registerForActivityResult()
In this NFC Activity I am calling **nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode()** in onResume()
and **nfcAdapter.disableReaderMode()** in onPause

So after sending a bunch of commands Activity return result to fragment through setResult().

.

**Problem is:**
Sometimes happens that NFC stops discovering tag.

.

**Flow is next:**

Fragment -> NFCActivity -> tap card to phone -> TAG discovered -> send 5 APDU commands to card and get result -> return result to Fragment to handle

-> then Fragment opens NFCActivity again to send another commands list -> tap card to phone -> NFC TAG is not discovering for 5-20 seconds. (So I need to wait like 10 seconds and tap card again.

.

**What can be the problem?**
Maybe I use **tag** / **isoDep** in wrong way?
Or maybe NFC can't be used to many times for short period of time?

Thank you!

Code:

```
    // in activity onResume()
    fun enableReaderMode(activity: NFCCryptoHandlerActivity) {
        nfcAdapter!!.enableReaderMode(
            activity,
            activity,
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
            Bundle()
        )
    }

    // in activity onPause()
    fun disableReaderMode(activity: NFCCryptoHandlerActivity) {
        nfcAdapter?.disableReaderMode(activity)
    }


    override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
        this@MainActivity.tag = tag
        isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag)
        isoDep?.timeout = 200000
    }



    private fun sendCommandArray(apduCommands: List<ApduCommand>) {
        thread {
            try {
                isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag)
                isoDep?.connect()

                if (isoDep!!.isConnected) {
                    apduCommands.forEach { apduCommand ->
                        val result = isoDep?.transceive(apduCommand.bytes)

                        runOnUiThread {
                            // post result in UI 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) { } 
            
            finally {
                try {
                    isoDep?.close();
                } catch (e: Exception) { }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is always good to send little sized commands. Recommend you not to use commands with more than 100 bytes. It was what I faced on my NFC project.

Comment: @AmrahAziz thanks! Actually I do not send commands more than 100 bytes, most of the commands not more than let's say 12-26 bytes. But sometimes it's 70-80 bytes

Comment: It has been known for there to be some bugs in some hardware on the frequency of the "presence" checks. Instead of providing a empty `Bundle` to the enable command, add option to control the frequency of "presence" checks yourself (something like `bundle.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);` in Java for a 250ms time between "presence" checks)

Comment: The other thought is that you should actively close your connection to the Tag when you have finished handling each Tag detection, e.g. at the end of `onTagDiscovered` call `isoDep?.close()` as your long timeout might be blocking new Tag detection.

Comment: @Andrew thank you! Will add EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY. Actually I do isoDep?.close() right after send all commands. I mean once tag discovered I start sending commands, when last command from array is sent and result received - I'm closing tag.

Comment: @Andrew as I understand you have a huge experience working with NFC in Android, maybe you can share your nfc settings like timeout, etc?)

Comment: I do less with isoDep but unless you are expecting the Tag to take a long time to respond to your commands I would not bother changing the default timeout.