# Does Android NFC need delay after connection?

Tags: android, nfc

I have written an Android app to connect to an NFC Card (NFC type A) via APDUs. I connect and send select command to card successfully on debug mode when I have a few breakpoints. But when I install the app on the phone and run it, the application crashes. when I add a delay to the routine by `Thread.sleep`, after connecting to tag and before selecting the applet, the problem is solved. Is this delay required? and what is that for? If I place 1500ms of delay, it still crashes and it surely needs 2000ms delay!!!
In addition, I don't know how to handle single detection of NFC card in each touch an Android card detection sound is buzzed multiple times.

It would be great if somebody can help me on this.
These are the codes I have used:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package nfcapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    byte[] resp;
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    static final byte[] APPLET_AID = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06};
    static final byte[] APPLET_PIN = {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04};
    static final byte[] APDU_SELECT = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
    TextView tv_status;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv_status = findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on device NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if ( NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            if (NfcA.get(tag) != null) {
                NfcA nfcaTag = NfcA.get(tag);
                try {
                    nfcaTag = SCConnect(nfcaTag);
                    if (nfcaTag == null) {
                        finish();
                    }
                    tv_status.append("Connected To NFC Card Successfully!\n");

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    
                    resp = SCSelectApplet(nfcaTag, APPLET_AID);
                    tv_status.append("SCSelectApplet: " + byteArrayToHexString(resp) + "\n");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    tv_status.append("IOException : "+ e.getMessage().toString() + "\n");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unsupported tag technology", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }
    }

    private NfcA SCConnect(NfcA nfcA) throws IOException {
        nfcA.connect();
        if (!nfcA.isConnected()) {
            return null;
        }
        return nfcA;
    }
    
    private static byte[] SCSelectApplet(NfcA nfcA, byte[] AID) throws IOException {
        if(!nfcA.isConnected()) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] APDU = new byte[13];
        System.arraycopy(APDU_SELECT,0,APDU,0,5);
        if (AID.length != 0) {
            Array.setByte(APDU,4,(byte)AID.length);
            System.arraycopy(AID,0,APDU,5,AID.length);
        }
        byte[] resp = nfcA.transceive(APDU);
        return resp;
    }

    private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) return null;
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFCApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:hint="Status" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `application crashes` means nothing really. Post the stacktrace

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thank you for your answer Marcin. I solved the crash problem. That was due to trying to find the length of an empty byte array happening when card does not respond. I read few related posts about Android NFC. I think that delay is needed to help balance card power consumption from mobile NFC. What do you think?

Comment: There are obvious problems with your code, you are doing NFC comms on the main thread which is against recommendations and then adding a sleep on the main thread which might cause an ANR. I would recommend that you don't use `enableForegroundDispatch` and use `enableReaderMode` instead see an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819