# Why NFC_TAG keep discovered even the app closed?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I want my app to only start scanning in a specific fragment. But currently my app keep detecting NFC tag even when the app closed. How can I set it to only scan for NFC in a specific fragment/activity?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Testing"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Manifest Intent filters to detect tags, they are primary used now to start/restart your app via NFC when it is not running/in the foreground.

Instead use only a foreground dispatch method like `enableReaderMode` ([Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))) and [An Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920307/how-to-write-ndef-records-to-nfc-tag/64921434#64921434) which is only active when your app is in the Foreground

Also NFC is really only associated with an Activity not Fragments, but you can make it only seem active when a certain Fragment is being shown. You do this by detecting Tags in the Activity but if the correct Fragment is not shown you just do nothing with the detected Tag. When your Fragment you want to handle NFC is shown set a Flag that changes the behaviour of the Tag handling code, to actually do something.

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation and for the documentation you give. It really help me

Answer (score 0):

You just call this one when you pause for specific activities.

```
nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(getActivity());
```