# Android Kotlin: NFC Tag not reading by the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, nfc

I've recently created an NFC tag reader app, but unfortunately, my app doesn't seem to recognize it but it was detected by the system (mobile) software and redirect to the inbuild NFC scanner. I've double-checked my code and connections and seem look corrected as I follows the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/nfc/nfc), but I'm still facing this issue.

> **Issue:** App not detect the NFC callback at `onNewIntent()`, it redirect to the in-build feature. Works fine with other (downloaded) apps.

***AndroidManifest.xml*:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFCApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".AnotherActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***nfc_tech_filter.xml*** at `<project-root>/res/xml`:

```xml
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

***MainActivity***:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.d("CHKI", "NEW NFC DETECTED")

        if (intent?.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) {
            Log.d("CHKI", "ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED")
        }

        if (intent?.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) {
            Log.d("CHKI", "ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED")
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, and if so, what steps did you take to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data is on the NFC Tag? Try changing "text/plain" to "\*/\*" in your manifest. If you want to detect NFC only when your app is running, then using a foreground detect method like `enableReaderMode` is better.

Comment: Plain text is in the NFC tag. Okay I will try with the `enableReaderMode `.
Will inform if it is working. Thanks

Comment: Example of `enableReadermode` https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your support, The Issue is resolved & I share the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `onResume` & `onPause` and now NFC is working fine with my existing code. These methods are used to enable and disable the foreground dispatch system.

Here is the code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // existing code
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        // existing code
    }

    // Added new
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )
        nfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null)
    }

    // Added new
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        nfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }
}
```