# Write URL into ntag215 with password protection

Tags: java, android, nfc, password-protection, ntag21x

i am trying to write a URL into an ntag215 that has password protection but i am not being able to do so. This password protection has been set by me. This means i know PWD and PACK for the tag, and i have correctly overwriten them in the tag (together with AUTH0, AUTH_LIM and PROT). The thing is that the authentication of the tag is correct, this means that when i try to verify the PACK i receive with the PACK i have, both are the same. Here is an example of how i do this. The functions i use here are ok.

```
URLActivateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myTag == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "my tag not detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, Error_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Ndef ndef_writable = Ndef.get(myTag);
                    NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(myTag);

                    try {
                        nfcA.connect(); // Intenta conectar con la tag NFC


                        if (ndef_writable.isWritable()) {
                            // Obtener la contraseña en formato de bytes
                            byte[] passwordBytes = getPasswordBytes();

                            try {
                                // Enviar el comando PWD_AUTH al tag NFC
                                byte[] response = nfcA.transceive(new byte[] {
                                        (byte) 0x1B, // PWD_AUTH
                                        passwordBytes[0], passwordBytes[1], passwordBytes[2], passwordBytes[3]
                                });

                                if ((response != null) && (response.length >= 2)) {
                                    // Obtener PACK para verificar la autenticidad del tag
                                    byte[] pack = Arrays.copyOf(response, 2);

                                    // Verificar PACK para confirmar que el tag es auténtico
                                    if (verifyPack(pack)) {
                                        nfcA.close();
                                        // Autenticación exitosa, ahora puedes realizar la escritura en la tag

                                        writeURLtoTag(myTag, createUriMessage(edit_url.getText().toString()));
                                        Toast.makeText(context, Write_Succes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//... rest of the code
```

However the issue comes in the function writeURLtoTag. This is the function:

```
public void writeURLtoTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage message)  {
        if (tag != null) {
            try {
                Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);

                if (ndefTag == null) {
                    // Let's try to format the Tag in NDEF
                    NdefFormatable nForm = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
                    if (nForm != null) {
                        // Formatear la etiqueta si es necesario
                        nForm.connect();
                        nForm.format(message);
                        nForm.close();
                    } else {
                        // Manejar el caso en que la etiqueta no sea compatible con NDEF ni NdefFormatable
                        Log.e("TagAuth", "Tag not compatible with NDEF");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Tag not compatible with NDEF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Verificar el contenido actual de la etiqueta antes de escribir
                    NdefMessage currentMessage = ndefTag.getCachedNdefMessage();
                    if (currentMessage != null) {
                        // Puedes imprimir o manejar el contenido actual de la etiqueta si es necesario
                        Log.d("TagAuth", "Current NDEF Message: " + currentMessage.toString());
                    }

                    // Continuar con la conexión y escritura en la etiqueta
                    ndefTag.connect();
                    try {
                        checkTagStatus(tag);
                        ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(message);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Write Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("TagAuth", "IOException during writeNdefMessage: " + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IOException during writeNdefMessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ndefTag.close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("TagAuth", "Error during write Ndef: " + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Writing Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Everytime i try to do ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(message) i get an IO exception "IOException during writeNdefMessage: null". I don't understand this. Why, if i have been authenticated, i can't write a new URL to the tag? Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem, but it is definitely a problem. It seems you are calling various Nfc methods from the main thread, the documentation says you must not do this because they block the main thread and if these blocking operations are cancelled to unblock the main thread you will get IOExceptions. You don't show how you have got the NFC data sent to your App. In my experience that unless you use `enableReaderMode` you will get IOExceptions when writing (enableReaderMode nicely does everything on it's own thread for you).

Comment: hi @Andrew thanks for the answer. However i don't understand something. You say i must not call various NFC methods. I think you are referring to the lines where i call nfca.get(tag) and ndef.get(get). I have also read this in other posts. However i didn't have any other way of writing in the tag after having connected and authenticated to it.

You mention however, to use `enableReaderMode`. Could you give me an example of how to use this? i haven't found ny example of how to use it to *write* in an NFC tag with it. Please tell me if you need any other piece of code!

Comment: The docs say you must not call things that do RF activity from the main thread e.g `Ndef.connect` `Ndef.writeNdefMessage` `NfcA.connect` `NfcA.transceive` from the main UI thread as these block and you might get ANR's and operation cancellations. You either need to create your own thread or use other methods to call these methods in background. You should not call these directly from the things like `OnClickListener` as this is run on the UI thread. An example of enableReaderMode https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819

Comment: Also for reliable NFC operations they should not be triggered by the UI. i.e. The flow of present Tag -> click button is bad. The flow should be Click button -> present Tag. (The button just changes the response from doing nothing when a Tag is presented to doing something).

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thanks a lot for your comments. However, i have been stuck with this problem for days and i want to give a last try to it before changing the whole app structure. What i would like to know is if it is poissible to write the new URL using the `nfca.transcieve()` method instead of using `ndef.writeNdefMessage()`. I would like to use it after the condition `if (verifyPack(pack))` to write the URL https://www.youtube.com/ for example. I know the command WRITE for ntag21x is A2h but i don't know how to write a full URL. Is important for me to make this app work, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible for you to write the NdefMessage directly using NfcA.transcieve but you will need to do a bit of extra work. You should be able to create the Ndef message as normal then `NdefMessage.toByteArray` to get the raw message. You would then need to split it in to 4 byte chunks and pad the last 4 byte chunk with zeros to make it 4 bytes. Then transcieve each 4 bytes with a write command starting at page `04h` and checking each returned NAK until all the byte chunks have been written or you run out of space.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew you are helping me a lot. I will try it now. I woul also want to ask one more question. Is it possible to authenticate just by using `ndef`? This is sending the `PWD` and veryfing the `PACK` with `ndef`, in a similar way as i am already doing with `nfca.transcieve()`. If this is possible then writing the message and formatting the previous content would be easier.

Comment: It should be possible to authenticate for ndef but I've never tried.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will try everything we have just spoken and reach you with anything i achive. Thanks a lot!