Android app not retrieving data when reading NFC - Android studio
Hi I need to integrate in my app the NFC reading feature. I thought I wrote everything and correctly, but it really does not work.
Manifest:
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

My code:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nfcAdapter = nfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);


        if(nfcAdapter==null) Toast.makeText(this, "No NFC option available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) Toast.makeText(this, "NFC disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) Toast.makeText(this, "NFC enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);


        Log.d("START", "pendingIntent");

        nFilter = new IntentFilter[]{
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED),
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED),
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED),
        };
        nTechList = new String [][] {
                new String[] {MifareClassic.class.getName()},
                new String[] {NfcA.class.getName()},
                new String[] {Ndef.class.getName()},
                new String[]{NfcB.class.getName()},
                new String[] {MifareUltralight.class.getName()}
        };

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        try{
            nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,pendingIntent,nFilter,nTechList);
            String result = processIntent(getIntent());
        }
        catch (Exception e ){
            Log.e("OnResume", "Error enabling NFC foreground dispatch");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (nfcAdapter != null) {
            try {
                nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                Log.e("ATHTAG", "Error disabling NFC foreground dispatch", ex);
            }
        }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        Log.d("OnNewIntent", "");
        if(){
            Log.v("OnNewIntent", "Action TAG");

        }
        if(){
            Log.v("OnNewIntent", "Action TECH");

        }
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            String result = processIntent(intent);

            Log.v("OnNewIntent", "Action Ndef");
            boolean response = checkIdentity(result); //controllo identità
            if(response) goToScanActivity(result); //se va bene vado all'attività di scansione
            else Toast.makeText(this, "ERRORE: Operatore non riconosciuto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

 private String processIntent(Intent intent){
        Log.v("processIntent", "Beginning");

        Parcelable[]rawMessage = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(nfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        byte[] uid = intent.getByteArrayExtra(nfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(nfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if(rawMessage!=null){
            Log.v("processIntent", "NOT null");
            NdefMessage[] ndefMessages = new NdefMessage[rawMessage.length]; 
            for(int i =0; i<rawMessage.length;++i){
                ndefMessages[i]=(NdefMessage) rawMessage[i];
                NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessages[i].getRecords();
                for(int j=0; j<ndefRecords.length;j++){
                    result += ndefRecords[j].getPayload();
                }
                result+= '\n';
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result: "+result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return result;
        }
        else Log.e("processIntent", "null");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR No message to display" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "ERROR No message to display";
    }




Placing some Logs around I checked that everything is ok up until processIntent(Intent intent): no matter what, Parcelable[] rawMessage is null.

The latest tag I am using to do the testing is a NTAG216 ISO 14443-3A. I tried also writing a simple text string in the memory, but still, the message is null.


So my problem is not that it does not detect the tag, but rather it is like it's not able to detect any data in the memory. What am I doing wrong?
Tnx

PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE should be PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE otherwise the NFC system cannot place the NFC data in the intent. Also I would not use the OLD intent based system for NFC, it has a number of issues. Use the newer and better enableReaderMode API see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819 for example.
